# Leave node attributes empty on closing

Tags: r, overpass-api, xml2

I'm using R's `xml2` package to write a query to the [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), which is not strictly xml but sure works a lot like it.

I have an issue, however, where the `xml2` package writes node attributes on opening and on closing.

```r
# build xml object for osm query
script <- xml2::xml_new_document() %>%
  xml2::xml_add_child("osm-script")

union <- xml2::xml_add_child(script, 'union into="_"')
query <- xml2::xml_add_child(union, 'query type="way"')
script
{xml_document}
<osm-script>
[1] <union into="_">\n  <query type="way"/>\n</union into="_">
```

The `into="_"` attribute is on the opening and closing of the node; I'm not super familiar with xml, but in Overpass having this attribute there makes the query fail.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpectedly, xml2 is much smarter than other xml libraries. Turns out you don't need to put the full attribute string in the node creation...

```
script <- xml2::xml_new_document() %>%
  xml2::xml_add_child("osm-script")
union <- xml2::xml_add_child(script, "union", into = "_")
query <- xml2::xml_add_child(union, "query", type = "way")
script
#> {xml_document}
#> <osm-script>
#> [1] <union into="_">\n  <query type="way"/>\n</union>
```

Thanks to Jim Hester on the [xml2 issues page](https://github.com/hadley/xml2/issues/113#issuecomment-233817246)